# Why is SVG imported as IMG in React not working?

Tags: image, svg, create-react-app, filepath

I don't understand why this SVG is not displaying with create-react-app; in most cases it's producing errors which I don't understand. I think it's a problem with the file path but it looks correct to me! I've read all the resources I can find and tried everything but something is still wrong. Thank you in advance for your help.

The closest I can get to it working is like this:

```
<img src="../assets/images/logo-cool-earth-white.svg" alt="Cool Earth" />
```

The alt text is displayed in the browser with the tooltip inside the inspector: "File could not be found".

I have also tried this:

```
import CoolEarth from '../assets/images/logo-cool-earth-white.svg';
...
<img src={CoolEarth} alt="Cool Earth" />
```

and this:

```
import {ReactComponent as CoolEarth} from '../assets/images/logo-cool-earth-white.svg';
...
<CoolEarth />
```

(The `img` component is placed inside a `function () { return (<><div></div></>) }`)

The error message I get for the last 2 attempts is:

```
Compiled with problems:

ERROR in ./src/assets/images/logo-cool-earth-white.svg

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/file-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at getHashDigest (/Users/username/Documents/Clients/clientname/crypto-transfer/working crypto-transfer/node_modules/loader-utils/lib/getHashDigest.js:46:34)
    at /Users/username/Documents/Clients/clientname/crypto-transfer/working crypto-transfer/node_modules/loader-utils/lib/interpolateName.js:113:11
    at String.replace (<anonymous>)
    at interpolateName (/Users/username/Documents/Clients/clientname/crypto-transfer/working crypto-transfer/node_modules/loader-utils/lib/interpolateName.js:110:8)
    at Object.loader (/Users/username/Documents/Clients/clientname/crypto-transfer/working crypto-transfer/node_modules/file-loader/dist/index.js:29:48)
```

Here is the file structure:

```
src >
 components >
  Video.js
 assets >
  images >
   logo-cool-earth-white.svg
 App.js
```

Video.js (containing the SVG) is rendered inside App.js

SVG file looks like this:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 95 90" style="enable-background:new 0 0 95 90;" xml:space="preserve">
<path class="st0" d="...">
...
</svg>
```

Comment: This and similar questions get asked here every day and the solution is almost always the same. Your path name is probably wrong.

Comment: @Rob I know, and I've read many of them but unfortunately they haven't helped solve my problem. I've specified the filepath used and the file structure in the question and can't see how it's wrong. If you can, I would greatly appreciate your advice.

Comment: hi @Freja - which version of node are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(With the help from a friend) I was able to find a solution to this problem.

Place the SVG into a react component like this:

```
import React from 'react';

function CoolEarth() {
  return (
   <svg>...</svg>
  );
};

export default CoolEarth;
```

Place CoolEarth.js into a subfolder of the components folder and import it into Video.js like this:

```
import CoolEarth from "./svg/CoolEarth";
```

If anyone knows why this works over my other attempts, please do elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an **index.js** file in the icons folder. In the file create a component:

```
import {ReactComponent as CoolEarth} from './CoolEarth.svg';

export {CoolEarth}
```

and use as a component:
e.x.

```
<CoolEarth />
```